# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified Junit and Mockito

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mocking

Good Morning people!
I am doing unit test in my spring boot application but it launches the next exception:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified;**

This is my method:

```
@RestController
public class controlador {

@Autowired(required = true)
JdbcTemplate conn;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/getlistadopantallatab", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json",produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getListadoPantallaTab(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> dto) {
    Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = null;
    try {
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(conn)
                .withCatalogName("CCR_PACKAGE")
                .withProcedureName("getListadoPorPantallaTab");

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(dto);
        simpleJdbcCallResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Se ha lanzado la siguiente excepcion: " + e);
    }
    return simpleJdbcCallResult;
}
```

and it is my test:

```
public class controladorTest {

static controlador mockInstanced;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception {
    mockInstanced= new controlador();
    mockInstanced.conn = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
}

/**
 * Test of getListadoPantallaTab method, of class controlador.
 */
@Test
public void testGetListadoPantallaTab() {
    System.out.println("Test unitario getListadoPantallaTab: ");
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    Map<String, Object> dto = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("Inicio", 1);
        put("fin", 15);
    }};

    mockInstanced.getListadoPantallaTab(dto);
}
```

Somebody knows what i am doing wrong?

PD: Sorry for my english, i am spanish!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to test a class, which uses beans without starting the Spring's application context.

There are multiple ways to solve your problem.

1. Make spring to run application context. You can do that by adding: `@SpringBootTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotations to your test class. Something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class controladorTest {
...
}
```

This way the Spring application context will be created - but you don't have to mock your controller instance - as it's already created - so you can just autowire it:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class controladorTest {
    @Autowired
    private controlador controlador;
...
}
```

and remove next lines :

```
static controlador mockInstanced;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception {
    mockInstanced= new controlador();
    mockInstanced.conn = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
}
```

2. Another theoretical way is to mock `JdbcTemplate` and inject it into your mock using `@InjectMocks` - but I wouldn't recommend to do it - too cumbersome and fragile solution.
3. Also, taking into account, that your controller uses only `JdbcTemplate` as a dependency, you can use an embedded [DB for Junit](https://github.com/zapodot/embedded-db-junit) and create the `JdbcTemplate` manually and inject it to your controller - in this case, there is no need to create the application context and you can just manually create a controller instance and pass JdbcTemplate to it. See [this](https://github.com/zapodot/embedded-db-junit)  for more info

So after step 1, your code should look like the following:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class controladorTest {

    @Autowired
    private controlador controlador;

    /**
     * Test of getListadoPantallaTab method, of class controlador.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetListadoPantallaTab() {
        System.out.println("Test unitario getListadoPantallaTab: ");
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        Map<String, Object> dto = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("Inicio", 1);
            put("fin", 15);
        }};

        controlador.getListadoPantallaTab(dto);
    }
}
```

By the way, please look at [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - to make your code more readable.

More info about testing with spring [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html)

Comment: Hi @Edu Martinez, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.